# Group key value from flat db by key parts only

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, lodash

I receive some data from a flat db as follows:

```
[{
        key: "user_15478",
        value: "xxx"
    }, {
        key: "user_name_15478",
        value: "xxx"
    }, {
        key: "user_age_15478",
        value: 5
    }, {
        key: "user_24547",
        value: "xxx"
    }, {
        key: "user_name_24547",
        value: "xxx"
    }, {
        key: "user_age_24547",
        value: 12
    }, {
        key: "user_42412",
        value: "xxx"
    }, {
        key: "user_name_42412",
        value: "xxx"
    }, {
        key: "user_age_42412",
        value: 42
    }
]
```

What would be the easier way, in vanila js or with a lib like lodash to transform it grouped by the digit in the key (15478, 24547 etc).

For example:

```
[{
        15478: [{
                key: "user_15478",
                value: "xxx"
            }, {
                key: "user_name_15478",
                value: "xxx"
            }, {
                key: "user_age_15478",
                value: 5
            }
        ]
    }, {
        24547: [{
                key: "user_24547",
                value: "xxx"
            }, {
                key: "user_name_24547",
                value: "xxx"
            }, {
                key: "user_age_24547",
                value: 12
            }
        ]
    }, {
        42412: { {
                key: "user_42412",
                value: "xxx"
            }, {
                key: "user_name_42412",
                value: "xxx"
            }, {
                key: "user_age_42412",
                value: 42
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and inside callback function check use `lastIndexOf` to get the last `_`. Then check the accumulator object if there exist any key which is same as the number. If not then create the key and add value to it.

```js
let data = [{
    key: "user_15478",
    value: "xxx"
  },
  {
    key: "user_name_15478",
    value: "xxx"
  },
  {
    key: "user_age_15478",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    key: "user_24547",
    value: "xxx"
  },
  {
    key: "user_name_24547",
    value: "xxx"
  },
  {
    key: "user_age_24547",
    value: 12
  },
  {
    key: "user_42412",
    value: "xxx"
  },
  {
    key: "user_name_42412",
    value: "xxx"
  },
  {
    key: "user_age_42412",
    value: 42
  }
];

let newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const _key = curr.key;
  const getNum = _key.substr(_key.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, _key.length);
  if (!acc[getNum]) {
    acc[getNum] = []
  }
  acc[getNum].push(curr)
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log([newData])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very fast response, i actually think my data structure is a bit different thant the example i provided because when i try your code on my data i get data.reduce is not a function, on the example data it work.

Here the two data structure (original and example):
https://pasteboard.co/JnevTJp.jpg

Comment: Ok i found the solution, my data is an object so i just wrapped it with Object.values(data) like: let newData = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, curr) => { etc...
Work perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your input array is not sorted then you first need to sort it based on `key`.
So after being sorted it will look like this:

```
[{key: "user_15478",
 value: "xxx"
 },
{key: "user_24547",
 value: "xxx"
 },
.... //then _age wise
{key: "user_age_42412",
 value: "xxx"
 },
... //then _name wise 
{key: "user_name_42412",
 value: "xxx"
 },
]
```

and then simply keep on pushing the objects to accumulator using `reduce`

```js
let arr= [ { key: "user_15478", value: "xxx" }, { key: "user_name_15478", value: "xxx" }, { key: "user_age_15478", value: 5 }, { key: "user_24547", value: "xxx" }, { key: "user_name_24547", value: "xxx" }, { key: "user_age_24547", value: 12 }, { key: "user_42412", value: "xxx" }, { key: "user_name_42412", value: "xxx" }, { key: "user_age_42412", value: 42 }, ];

arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a.key > b.key ? 1 : -1)

let result=arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  let field = val.key.split("_")
  if (field.length === 2) {
    acc[field[1]] = [{ ...val
    }]
  }
  else
  acc[field[2]].push(val)
  return acc;
}, {})
let wrappedResult=Object.keys(result).map(key=>({[key]:result[key]}))
console.log(wrappedResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const transformed = data.reduce((acc, user) => {
    const [ key ] = user.key.match(/\d+$/);
    if (!(key in acc)) {
        acc[+key] = [];
    }
    acc[+key].push(user);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Given `data` is:

```js
[{
    key: "user_15478",
    value: "xxx"
}, {
    key: "user_name_15478",
    value: "xxx"
}, {
    key: "user_age_15478",
    value: 5
}, {
    key: "user_24547",
    value: "xxx"
}, {
    key: "user_name_24547",
    value: "xxx"
}, {
    key: "user_age_24547",
    value: 12
}, {
    key: "user_42412",
    value: "xxx"
}, {
    key: "user_name_42412",
    value: "xxx"
}, {
    key: "user_age_42412",
    value: 42
}];
```